# How to load multiple .env files or load .env from parent directory in Laravel 6

Tags: php, docker, configuration, laravel-6, dotenv

For a Laravel app using docker-compose I have the following (simplified) folder structure:

```
Project
|
|-- data
    |-- ...
|-- docker
    |-- ...
|-- laravel
    |-- app
    |-- ...
    |-- .env
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- .env
```

Docker-compose is set up to load database connection details from the `.env` file in the root folder of the project when constructing the containers. Laravel also needs these and I have to duplicate them in the `.env` file inside the laravel folder.

I would like to avoid this duplication. Ideally I would load both .env files in Laravel to avoid cluttering up the docker-compose .env with stuff that is only relevant to Laravel. But I would be almost as happy to just have the one .env file in the project root, provided there is a clean way to do it.

I have found no configuration setting but relevant methods `loadEnvironmentFrom()` and `useEnvironmentPath()` inside the `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` but I'm not sure where to call them from. I would extend Application, but it seems that Dotenv is already loaded by the time it is instantiated in `/boostrap/app.php`

Hopefully there is somewhere outside of the vendor dolder where I could change the path or load a different .env file in time for it to be used by the configuration files. Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `useEnvironmentPath()` in `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->useEnvironmentPath($env_path);
```

Or as a solution:

```
$app->useEnvironmentPath(
  dirname(__DIR__, 2)
);
```

`__DIR__` returns full path of current file (since you are in `bootstrap/app.php`)
`dirname(__DIR__, 2)`, goes back 2 steps form your file location (In your case, it returns your `Project` directory path)

Now Laravel should read your new `.env` file.

**-- UPDATE --**

For HTTP applications, update `app/Http/Kernel.php` :

```php
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
//////
    /**
     * Create a new HTTP kernel instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application  $app
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
    {
        $app->useEnvironmentPath(dirname(__DIR__, 3));
        parent::__construct($app, $router);
    }
```

And for console applications, edit `app/Console/Kernel.php`:

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;

/////
    /**
     * Create a new console kernel instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application  $app
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Application $app, Dispatcher $events)
    {
        $app->useEnvironmentPath(dirname(__DIR__, 3));
        parent::__construct($app, $events);
    }
```

And `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`:

```php
public function boot() {
    app()->useEnvironmentPath(dirname(__DIR__, 3));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only half works. That is to say artisan loads the correct .env file and I can run migrations and seeds and queries on through tinker; but when I request a route, any route, over HTTP I either get a db connect error, or if the route doesn't involve a db query, an unresolvable missing app key error, which indicates the .env is not being loaded.

Comment: After further testing I realized that the reason your original solution was working with artisan and not over HTTP was because the apache container had the laravel directory mapped to /var/www/html and had no access to the parent directory ‍♂️. I realized this when I tried running the project locally where your solution works fine. So I've selected your answer as correct since it does do what I asked for, but it's looking like I will probably end up configuring docker to read the env file from the laravel directory instead of using your solution.